# OpenMP measure time correct

Tags: c++, performance, timer, openmp

I want to measure performance of parallel program implemented using C++(openMP)

Recommended way to measure time using this technology is

```
double start = omp_get_wtime();

// some code here

double end = omp_get_wtime();
printf_s("Time = %.16g", end - start);
```

But i get time near 0, despite i wait for program about 8 seconds.
All other methods to get execution time return 0.0
Also tried use these code examples

```
DWORD st = GetTickCount();
time_t time_start = time(NULL);
clock_t start = clock();
auto t1 = Clock::now();     

time_t time_finish = time(NULL);
DWORD fn = GetTickCount();
clock_t finish = clock();
auto t2 = Clock::now();
```

All without success. Program spend running a lot of time. But results always zero. (In debug and release mode)
If i debug step-by-step results differs from zero.

Here is my parallel #pragma directive

```
#pragma omp parallel default(none) private(i) shared(nSum, nTheads, nMaxThreads, nStart, nEnd, data, modulo) {
    #pragma omp master
    nTheads = omp_get_num_threads();
    nMaxThreads = omp_get_max_threads();

    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = nStart; i < nEnd; ++i)
    {           
        #pragma omp atomic
        nSum += (power(data[i], i) * i) % modulo;
    }
}
```

Where is my error? Please help me. I spend a lot of time with this problem.

Comment: This posts doesn't help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874214/measure-execution-time-in-c-openmp-code?rq=1 because i am using Windows.

Comment: Did you include <omp.h>? If not, maybe omp_get_wtime() is being treated as returning an int, which would be sub-optimal.

Comment: @JimCownie omp.h was included. I solve my problem by moving 
double start = omp_get_wtime() to the very beginning of the program
and double end = omp_get_wtime() to the very end. And it worked. 
But i can't understand how this helped! All time consuming code was wrapped  in previous example too.