# Gaussian Elimination in OpenMP - Performance Problems

Tags: optimization, parallel-processing, openmp, linear-algebra

I'm new to openMP, and I was trying to parallelize a Gaussian Elimination, and I'm having troubles with performance. I'm compiling the code below using:

gcc -o gaussian_elimination gaussian_elimination.c -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas -fopenmp -Wall

And setting the number of threads on the terminal with export OMP_NUM_THREADS

And my problem is that the parallel version of this code is running way slower than the serial version of the same. I believe that this is because I declared #pragma parallel for inside the external loop, and this would force openMP to create and destroy thread at each iteration, which would be incredibly costly, but I haven't seen any other clear way to do the same kind of operation, and I don't think I can exchange the external loop with the internal parallel ones.

I'm probably missing something, but I have not found any other forum threads here commenting on this particular problem. As far as execution correctness goes, my code seems to be functioning alright, the problem is just performance-wise.

Thanks in Advance

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_linalg.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>

#define DEBUG_MODE false

int random_matrix(double *A, int N,long long int seed);

int print_matrix(double *A, int N);

int print_vector(float *b,int N);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  int N=1000;
  int i,j,k,l,i_p,s,err,D=N+1;
  long long int seed=9089123498274; // just a fixed seed only not to bother
  double *A,pivot,sw,tmp,begin,end,time_spent;
  double *Aref,*bref;
  gsl_matrix_view gsl_m; 
  gsl_vector_view gsl_b;
  gsl_vector *gsl_x;
  gsl_permutation *gsl_p;

  /* Input */

  //scanf("%d",&N);

  A = (double*)malloc(N*(N+1)*sizeof(double));
  if(A==NULL){
    printf("Matrix A not allocated\n");
    return 1;
  }

  Aref = (double*)malloc(N*N*sizeof(double));
  if(Aref==NULL){
    printf("Matrix A not allocated\n");
    return 1;
  }
  bref = (double*)malloc(N*sizeof(double));
  if(bref==NULL){
    printf("Vector B not allocated\n");
    return 2;
  }

  /*
  for(i=0;i<N;i+=1)
    for(j=0;j<N;j+=1)
      scanf("%f",&(A[i*N+j]));

  for(i=0;i<N;i+=1)
    scanf("%f",&(b[i]));
  */

  /*
  for(i=0;i<N*N;i++)
    A[i]=(float) a_data[i];
  for(i=0;i<N;i+=1)
    b[i]=(float) b_data[i]; */

  err= random_matrix(A,N,seed);
  if(err!=0)
    return err;

  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    for(j=0;j<N;j+=1)
      Aref[i*N+j]= A[i*D+j];
  for(i=0;i<N;i+=1)
    bref[i]= A[i*D+N];//b[i];

  printf("GSL reference:\n");

  gsl_m = gsl_matrix_view_array (Aref, N, N);
  gsl_b = gsl_vector_view_array (bref, N);
  gsl_x = gsl_vector_alloc (N);
  gsl_p = gsl_permutation_alloc(N);

  begin = clock();

  gsl_linalg_LU_decomp(&gsl_m.matrix, gsl_p, &s);
  gsl_linalg_LU_solve(&gsl_m.matrix, gsl_p, &gsl_b.vector, gsl_x);

  end = clock();
  time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("gsl matrix solver: %lf s\n",time_spent);

  if(DEBUG_MODE==true)
   gsl_vector_fprintf(stdout,gsl_x,"%f");

  gsl_permutation_free(gsl_p);
  gsl_vector_free(gsl_x);  

  begin = omp_get_wtime();

  for(i=0;i<N;i+=1){

    i_p = i;
    pivot = fabs(A[i*D+i]);
    for(j=i;j<N;j+=1)
      if(pivot<fabs(A[j*D+i])){ 
        pivot = fabs(A[j*D+i]);
        i_p = j;
      }

    #pragma omp parallel for shared(i,N,A,i_p) private(j,sw)
    for(j=i;j<D;j+=1){
      sw = A[i*D+j];
      A[i*D+j] = A[i_p*D+j];
      A[i_p*D+j] = sw;
    }

    pivot=A[i*D+i];
    #pragma omp parallel for shared(i,D,pivot,A) private(j)
    for(j=0;j<D;j++)
      A[i*D+j]=A[i*D+j]/pivot;

    #pragma omp parallel for shared(i,A,N,D) private(tmp,j,k,l)
    for(j=i+1;j<N+i;j++){
      k=j%N;
      tmp=A[k*D+i];
      for(l=0;l<D;l+=1)
        A[k*D+l]=A[k*D+l]-tmp*A[i*D+l];
    }   
  }

  end = omp_get_wtime();
  time_spent = (end - begin);
  printf("omp matrix solver: %lf s\n",time_spent);

  /* Output */

  if(DEBUG_MODE==true){
    printf("\nCalculated: \n");
    for(i=0;i<N;i+=1)
      printf("%.6f \n",A[i*(N+1)+N]);
    printf("\n"); 
  }

  free(A);

  return 0;
}

int random_matrix(double *A, int N,long long int seed){
  int i,j;
  const gsl_rng_type * T;
  gsl_rng *r;
  gsl_rng_env_setup();

  T = gsl_rng_default;
  r = gsl_rng_alloc (T);

  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    for(j=0;j<=N;j++)
      A[i*(N+1)+j]= gsl_rng_uniform (r);

  gsl_rng_free (r);

  return 0;
}

int print_matrix(double *A, int N){
  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    for(j=0;j<=N+1;j++){
      if(j==0 || j==N || j==N+1)
        printf(" | ");

      printf("%.2f ",A[i*(N+1)+j]);

      if(j==N+1)
        printf("\n"); 
    }

  return 0;
}

int print_vector(float *b,int N){
  int i;

  for(i=0;i<N;i+=1)
    printf("%f\n", b[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

I updated the code above with the omp_get_wtime(), and now it reads as the wtime diminishing as I include more and more threads, so, it does behave as it should, although not as clean as I would like.

For 1000 x 1000 matrices I get 0.25 s for the GSL lib, 4.4 s for the serial omp run and 1.5 s for the 4-thread run.

For 3000 x 3000 matrices, I get ~ 9s for the GSL lib, ~ 117 s for the serial omp run and ~ 44 s for the 4 thread-run, thus at least adding more threads indeed speeds up the program!

Thanks a lot everyone

Comment: Call LAPACK. Stop reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Try compiling with optimization on. Use `-O3`.

Comment: @Jeff, I have no intention of using this code for production, I'm trying to learn openMP and a sugestion that I was given was to try implementing this algorithm using it. For daily use, I do use GSL, and I have used lapack also,

Comment: @Zboson, -O3 helped a lot, but it still didn't solve the problem, for 3k x 3k, the clocks on the code returned ~ 9s for GSL and ~ 98s for my code with 4 threads, and ~ 26s with one thread.

Comment: You need to do blocked updates the way LAPACK does with DGEMM to get decent performance. Hence my previous comment.

Comment: @Jeff, do you have any reference as to how is done in Lapack? I tried to look on netlib website, but the implementation is a bit dificult to read, I'm not very used to fortran. I wanted to at least be able to do an implementation that does not get slower as I raise de number of threads.

Comment: Try googling "dgemm+lu+factorization".  For example, http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/factor/node7.html connects the math to subroutines.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read the link and come back latter.

Comment: [Your next problem is `clock()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10874371/2542702). Replace it with `omp_get_wtime()`.

Comment: Ok, I understand now clock() is probably responsible for most of my initial reaction. I updated the code, and re-run it, I'm posting the updates on the original question.

Comment: Okay, at this point the comments by @Jeff come in. You have to do loop tiling. After about a year of effort you might get close to the efficiency of a good BLAS library such as openblas. [You can see I got about 50% of the Intel MKL for Cholesky factorization](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23063655/2542702).