# Why is serial execution taking less time than parallel?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, pragma

I have to add two vectors and compare serial performance against parallel performance. 
However, my parallel code seems to take longer to execute than the serial code.

**Could you please suggest changes to make the parallel code faster?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include "omp.h"
#define ull unsigned long long

using namespace std;

void parallelAddition (ull N, const double *A, const double *B, double *C)
{
    ull i;

    #pragma omp parallel for shared (A,B,C,N) private(i) schedule(static)
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
    }
}

int main(){

ull n = 100000000;
double* A = new double[n];
double* B = new double[n];
double* C = new double[n];

double time_spent = 0.0;


for(ull i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    A[i] = 1;
    B[i] = 1;
}

//PARALLEL
clock_t begin = clock();
parallelAddition(n, &A[0], &B[0], &C[0]);
clock_t end = clock();
time_spent += (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

cout<<"time elapsed in parallel : "<<time_spent<<endl;


//SERIAL 
time_spent = 0.0;
for(ull i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    A[i] = 1;
    B[i] = 1;
}
begin = clock();
for (ull i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
}
end = clock();
time_spent += (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
cout<<"time elapsed in serial : "<<time_spent;
return 0;
}
```

These are results:

*time elapsed in parallel :* **0.824808**

*time elapsed in serial :* **0.351246**

I've read on another thread that there are factors like spawning of threads, allocation of resources. But I don't know what to do to get the expected result.

---

EDIT:

**Thanks! @zulan and @Daniel Langr 's answers actually helped!**

**I used `omp_get_wtime()` instead of `clock()`.
It happens to be that `clock()` measures cumulative time of all threads as against `omp_get_wtime()` which can be used to measure the time elasped from an arbitrary point to some other arbitrary point**

This answer too answers this query pretty well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10874371/4305675

Here's the fixed code:

```
void parallelAddition (ull N, const double *A, const double *B, double *C)
{
    ....
}

int main(){

    ....


    //PARALLEL
    double begin = omp_get_wtime();
    parallelAddition(n, &A[0], &B[0], &C[0]);
    double end = omp_get_wtime();
    time_spent += (double)(end - begin);

    cout<<"time elapsed in parallel : "<<time_spent<<endl;



    ....

    //SERIAL
    begin = omp_get_wtime();
    for (ull i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
    }
    end = omp_get_wtime();
    time_spent += (double)(end - begin);
    cout<<"time elapsed in serial : "<<time_spent;
return 0;
}
```

RESULT AFTER CHANGES:

*time elapsed in parallel :* **0.204763**

*time elapsed in serial :* **0.351711**

Comment: What compilation flags did you use?

Comment: I am not sure, how much optimzation the compiler can do in this case, but did you consider using random values instead of the number `1`?

Comment: What is the value of `OMP_NUM_THREADS`? Can you please check the return value of `omp_get_num_threads()`?

Comment: I think the compiler will just remove the loops, since you never use `C[i]`. See also [on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/BkP6wV). You should try and print all values of `C` at the end.

Comment: @NathanOliver, while compiling i used -fopenmp. this is how i compiled: g++ -fopenmp 1.cpp -o 1

Comment: @DavideSpataro, which part of code should i check of `OMP_NUM_THREADS` ?. I checked at end of program and it is outputting `1`.

Comment: @NitishPrajapati Okay.  Do note that when benchmarking, you should turn on optimizations (`-O2` or `-O3`).  The optimizer can do a lot that could make your sequential loop run a lot faster like using SIMD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple factors that influence your measurements:

1. Use `omp_get_wtime()` as @zulan suggested, otherwise, you may actually calculate *combined CPU time*, instead of ***wall time***.
2. Threading has some overhead and typically **does not pay off for short calculations**. You may want to use higher `n`.
3. **"Touch" data in `C` array before running `parallelAddition`**. Otherwise, the memory pages are actually allocated from OS inside `parallelAddition`. Easy fix since C++11: `double* C = new double[n]{};`.

I tried your program for `n` being 1G and the last change reduced runtime of `parallelAddition` from 1.54 to 0.94 [s] for 2 threads. Serial version took 1.83 [s], therefore, the **speedup with 2 threads was 1.95**, which was pretty close to ideal.

Other considerations:

- Generally, if you profile something, **make sure that the program has some observable effect**. Otherwise, a compiler may optimize a lot of code away. Your array addition has no observable effect.
- Add some form of **`restrict` keyword** to the `C` parameter. Without it, a compiler might not be able to apply vectorization.
- If you are on a multi-socket system, take care about **affinity of threads and NUMA effects**. On my dual-socket system, runtime of a parallel version for 2 threads took 0.94 [s] (as mentioned above) when restricting threads to a single NUMA node (`numactl -N 0 -m 0`). Without `numactl`, it took 1.35 [s], thus 1.44 times more.

Comment: your point no. 1 actually helped! I've edited changes. Please suggest if I'm interpreting the results wrongly